# Tables grid lines are not equal with columncolor

Tags: tables, grids

I am trying to color the background headline of my tables. I am using `columncolor`, which works very well, but sadly, the grid lines does not look correct. Without `columncolor` the grid line looks fine.

Here is screenshot of the grid line, note the red marked grid lines. They are a little bit smaller.

[image]

Here is my latex code

```
\begin{table}[H]

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|X|X|}

\hline

\multicolumn{1}{|>{\columncolor[gray]{.9}}c|}{\textbf{A}} &
\multicolumn{1}{ >{\columncolor[gray]{.9}}c|}{\textbf{B}} &
\multicolumn{1}{ >{\columncolor[gray]{.9}}c|}{\textbf{C}} \\

\hline

1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline
1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline
1 & 2 & 3 \\

\hline

\end{tabularx}

\end{table}
```

What did I wrong? How could I improve the look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's only a problem with the viewer. Zoom on your picture, and you'll see no difference. However I would suggest a simpler approach: the `makecell` is designed to make a common formatting for column heads and, by default, their contents is centred, whatever be the alignment in its column. It also allows for line breaks and, in addition, these heads have less tight spacing.. Here is a code (together with yours):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.8}
\newcolumntype{g}{>{\columncolor{Gray}}c}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\cellcolor[gray]{.9}\bfseries}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|X|X|}

\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|>{\columncolor[gray]{.9}}c|}{\textbf{A}} &
\multicolumn{1}{ >{\columncolor[gray]{.9}}c|}{\textbf{B}} &
\multicolumn{1}{ >{\columncolor[gray]{.9}}c|}{\textbf{C}} \\
\hline
\thead{A} &
\thead{B} &
\thead{C} \\
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 \\
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 \\
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the `makecell` hint, I like that. Okay, I understand thats a viewer problem. Is there a way to fix this? Some people will read my paper also as pdf and I would like to present the a nice look too.

Comment: I'm afraid not, except for warning them. Perhaps increasing the rule widths. `Makecell` has commands for horizontal  lines: `\Xhline{thickness}` and `Xcline{*-*}{thickness}`. For vertical rules, replace `|` with `!{\vrule width xxpt}`. But if you want professional-looking tables, you'd rather consider suppressing all vertical rules — except for some special cases. Take a look at the `booktabs` package documentation.